# After Click Button do not open the new activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity, manifest

I have some problems to lunch a new activity after click in a button, I have review hundreds of times the code but I don't find the mistake which I think it is in the manifest.

Could you help me?

Manifest info:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.productioncontrolinventory"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.productioncontrolinventory.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.productioncontrolinventory.Editacountentry" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><activity android:name="com.example.productioncontrolinventory.Inputinventory" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity></application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity code:

```
case R.id.bInputInventory:
                //Go to Input screen
                try{
                    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.productioncontrolinventory.Inputinventory");
                    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ourClass);
                    startActivity(ourIntent);
                 }catch(ClassNotFoundException g){
                        g.printStackTrace();
                        }
                break;
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share your stacktrace! How do we know whether the exception is thrown or not. Provide your logcat output.

Comment: Empty it is like the button not operate but other buttons with other functions works... the same problem extends on the whole app so should be related to manifest i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using

```
Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.productioncontrolinventory.Inputinventory");
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ourClass);
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

OR simply

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Inputinventory.class);
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

Instead of

```
Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.productioncontrolinventory.Inputinventory");
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ourClass);
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

If none of this works , you should check  if your button is functional through any other command (like a toast notification etc).

Your manifest file looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

why dont u simply use:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Inputinventory.class );
startActivity(i);
```

if "Inputinventory.java" extends Fragment , make your intent this way:

```
Context context;
Intent intent = new Intent(context ,Inputinventory.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

note: In the second condition , you must initialize the context variable in the constructor!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
{
Button btn;
btn = (Button) findViewbyId(R.id.bInputInventory);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(this, Inputinventory.class);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        }
    });
}
```